# Mathtools' underbrackets and MinionPro

Tags: mathtools, minionpro, bugs

The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \underbracket{123}_{x}
  \underbracket[1pt]{123}_{x}
  \]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If one comments out the line including `MinionPro` things go back to normal. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Can you confirm that for the math symbols the `MinionPro` package loads `MnSymbol`?

Comment: @egreg, yup it does.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `\underbracket`

```
\providecommand*\underbracket{
  \@ifnextchar[
    {\MT_underbracket_I:w}
    {\MT_underbracket_I:w[\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim]}}
\def\MT_underbracket_I:w[#1]{
  \@ifnextchar[
    {\MT_underbracket_II:w[#1]}
    {\MT_underbracket_II:w[#1][.7\fontdimen5\textfont2]}}
\def\MT_underbracket_II:w[#1][#2]#3{%
  \mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##
    \crcr
      $\hfil\displaystyle{#3}\hfil$%
    \crcr
      \noalign{\kern .2\fontdimen5\textfont2 \nointerlineskip}%
      \upbracketfill {#1}{#2}%
    \crcr}}}
  \limits}
\def\upbracketfill#1#2{%
  \sbox\z@{$\braceld$}
  \edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{\the\ht\z@}%
  \upbracketend{#1}{#2}
  \leaders \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth #1 \hfill
  \upbracketend{#1}{#2}%
}
\def\upbracketend#1#2{\vrule \@height #2 \@width #1\relax}
```

We see that the command has two optional arguments; the default value for the optional arguments are, respectively, `\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim` and `.7\fontdimen5\textfont2`. Thus the call `\underbracket{123}` ends up into doing

```
\upbracketfill{\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim}{.7\fontdimen5\textfont2}
```

and those parameters are used nowhere else. The macro `\upbracketfill` defines `\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim` to be the same as the height of `$\braceld$`. This is the character used for terminating the `\downbracefill` operation connected to `\overbrace` (probably `\bracelu` should be used, but it doesn't really change the matter).

Now let's do an experiment (`MinionPro` uses `MnSymbol` for math):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt % tight bounding box

x\fbox{$\braceld$}

x\fbox{$\bracelu$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What do we get if we omit loading `MnSymbol`?

[image]

Do you see the problem? There are several, but in this context the main one is that the height of `\braceld` is *huge*. With the Computer Modern math font, the height of `\braceld` can be used as the height of the filler rule for `\underbrace` or `\overbrace`; this is not at all possible with `MnSymbol` and, indeed, `MnSymbol` changes the definitions of `\underbrace`, `\overbrace` and the connected macros.

What you can do is changing the default value to something still linked to the MnSymbol math fonts; here I use twice the thickness of the fraction line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\makeatletter
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\upbracketfill#1#2{%
  \edef\l_MT_bracketheight_fdim{\the\dimexpr 2\fontdimen8\textfont3}%
  \upbracketend{#1}{#2}%
  \leaders \vrule \@height \z@ \@depth #1 \hfill
  \upbracketend{#1}{#2}%
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff\showthe\catcode`@
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$\underbracket{123}_{x}$                           

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should I report this to the mathtools guys or to the MnSymbol guys?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That's a good question. ;-) I'd say `MnSymbol`, because they are changing `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` (more precisely, they don't make `\braceld` good for measuring things).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the last comment I do use Minion Pro in LaTeX. `MnSymbol` is quite important but I also use `MinionPro` and `mathalfa` with this options:

`\usepackage[mathlf,textlf,minionint,openg]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[bb=lucida,bbscaled=1,cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}`

To obtain full numbers I use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathlf,textlf,minionint,openg]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[bb=lucida,bbscaled=1,cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
  \[
  \underbracket{123}_{x}
  \underbracket[1pt]{123}_{x}
  \]
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question was not about the numbers.